# In android mysql using Wamp the Intent is not opening when echo is matched and in other case echo is not printing

Tags: php, android, wamp

I am practicing Android Studio with Wamp on Below case, When login is successful Message is printing and intent is opening, when registration is successful Message is not printing and Intent is not opening but Data is being inserted in Table

**Android Java Code of Background Task**

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result!= null && result.equalsIgnoreCase("Registration Succesful")) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, forgot.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else if(result!= null && result.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Successful")) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, afterlogin.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } }
```

**PHP Code**

```
   $query = mysqli_query($conn ,"select * FROM userinfo WHERE userid ='$userid'");   if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {  
echo"Email Exists";
}
else {
$sql= ("insert into userinfo( userid, username, password) values ('$userid','$username','$password');");
echo"Registration Succesful";
      if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
              die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

**Error**

> W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4663937 , only wrote 4663440

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I have mistakenly entered that question, the above is my doubt

Comment: How about you debug the value of `result` first: use this code to test: `Log.d("TAG", "Result: " + result);`. Do it inside the `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: Hi, yes the result appears on Logcat, but not coming on Alert window... till few days it was working. but no idea why its not working now, only registration not showing and opening intent

Comment: @ariefbayu... I have tried, the result is same. Showing the message on Pre Execute